# OR condition in update impacting performance

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have the below update. Table1 has 800K rows and is indexed in col3. Table2 has 50K rows and is indexed in col3.

-- Slow way ---

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET
    t1.col1 = 'VALUE1'
WHERE
    t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            table2 t2
        WHERE
            t2.col3 = t1.col3
            OR t2.col4 = 'VALUE3'
    )
```

However, with the 'OR' condition (it goes fast with an 'AND' one though), it seems it is not going by index when looking at both tables. Is there a workaround to this problem so the update can be done faster?

-- Fast way---

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET
    t1.col1 = 'VALUE1'
WHERE
    t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            table2 t2
        WHERE
            t2.col3 = t1.col3
            AND t2.col4 = 'VALUE3'
    )
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to update all rows in table1 if table2 has col4='VALUE3'? Without checking if rows are related between table1 and table2?

Comment: Your *fast* and *slow* statement perform two different updates, so please clarify, what you want to achieve.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov not sure if I'm following you here. What would be the alternative?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I would like to achieve my slow statement in a fast way.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I would like to update t1 if there are matching col3 and t2.col4 is 'VALUE3'.

Comment: The two statements are different. They do two different things. Which one does the correct thing? Once we know that, then we can help speed it up.

Comment: @AndyLester the first one (slow one)  is the correct one.

Comment: @jeiv Then I suggest deleting the other, non-working fast query from your question, because it is just confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your formulation can be deduced that you try to update one (or possible few) rows only and you want to perform it quickly.

So the first think that strikes out is a **missing index** on `table1.col2` that will be obviously needed to perform the index access the table with the predicate:

```
WHERE
    t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'
```

Similar for the subquery you will need an index on `table2.col4` (for the predicate `t2.col4 = 'VALUE3'`)

With this index setup, your original *slow* query will perform fine (provided that `t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'`  return only few rows). There is **no need to rewrite the stameent**.

You may check it on the execution plan that you should expect

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT                      |             |     1 |    27 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE                               | TABLE1      |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   FILTER                              |             |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TABLE1      |     1 |    27 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TABLE1_IDX2 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TABLE2      |     1 |    27 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS       |             |       |       |            |          |
|   7 |      BITMAP OR                        |             |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |       BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS   |             |       |       |            |          |
|*  9 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN               | TABLE2_IDX  |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |       BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS   |             |       |       |            |          |
|* 11 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN               | TABLE2_IDX2 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "TABLE2" "T2" WHERE "T2"."COL3"=:B1 OR 
              "T2"."COL4"='VALUE3'))
   4 - access("T1"."COL2"='VALUE2')
   9 - access("T2"."COL3"=:B1)
  11 - access("T2"."COL4"='VALUE3')
```

So basically the update is done with a one *index range scan*, combined with a `FILTER`
that checks the `exists` subquery implemented as two index range scans combined with a `BITMAP OR`

**Alternative Solution for Large Update**

If you have an opposite case and the predicate `t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'` returns a large number of rows (say 100K or more) you will 1) definitively not want to use an index access for the update (`FULL TABLE SCAN` will be more effective) and 2) you should *split* the statement in two updates.

If the table2 contains a row with  `col4 = 'VALUE3'` perform

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET
    t1.col1 = 'VALUE1'
WHERE
    t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'
```

otherwise perform

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET
    t1.col1 = 'VALUE1'
WHERE
    t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            table2 t2
        WHERE
            t2.col3 = t1.col3)
```

The reason for the *split* is simple, the first statement will update all the rows with `VALUE2` (large number) and you want a `FULL TABLE SCAN`to be deployed.

In the second case maximal 30K rows will be updated (cardinality of table2) and you can live with the `FILTER`ed execution plan similar as above.

This is a typical problem when *one statement* covers *two very distinct constellation* so the selected execution plan works in one case good and in other bad.

If you use two statement, one for each situation you avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, what could I do if t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'returned more than a few rows?

Comment: Updated the answer and understood that this is your problem. @jeiv

Answer (score 1):

You can try using two `exists`:

```
WHERE t1.col2 = 'VALUE2' AND
      ( EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM table2 t2
                WHERE t2.col3 = t1.col3
               ) OR
        EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM table2 t2
                WHERE t2.col4 = 'VALUE3'
               )
      )
```

For this two work best, you want indexes on `table2(col3)` and `table2(col4)`.

Comment: Would that work if the first condition was also an OR? Not related to the question, just wondering.

Comment: Not sure if I understood this one correctly. Wouldn't the second statement update all table1 if table2 has at least one entry with t2.col4 = 'VALUE3'?

Comment: @Jeiv . . . Yes.  That is what the code in your question does.

Answer (score 1):

**Break Up Your Update Statement to Two Statements**

For performance sake, split up the UPDATE into two statements.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET t1.col1 = 'VALUE1'
 WHERE t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'
   AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
          FROM table2 t2
 WHERE t2.col4 = 'VALUE3'
       ) ;


UPDATE table1 t1
   SET t1.col1 = 'VALUE1'
 WHERE t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'
   AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
          FROM table2 t2
 WHERE t2.col3 = t1.col3
       );
```

Why could this help?

-Correlated subqueries with a join behaving like a cartesian join under certain circumstances is begging for trouble.

-Distilling the logic results in two UPDATE statements that should have better performance.

---

If you know that table2's dataset includes at least one record
where `col4 = 'VALUE3'` (and perhaps always will), you can optimize this further (as Marmite Bomber indicates).

-Remove the correlated subquery altogether for the first update statement.

-No need to even execute the second update statement. The affected records result set will be a subset of the first update's statement.

Comment: You may also *optimize*, if the first statement updates some rows, you need not execute the second one update (as already the whole tabel1 was updated).

Comment: I modified the answer to take into consideration your thoughts and agree there are even more opportunities to optimize, especially if this is in a PLSQL block.

Comment: @PatrickBacon not sure if I understood this one correctly. Wouldn't the first update update all table1 if table2 has at least one entry with t2.col4 = 'VALUE3'?

Comment: Hi @jeiv, In all scenarios, `t1.col2 = 'VALUE2'` must be true for the update to occur.

Comment: @PatrickBacon oh, ok, I just understood it. I have just realised that I should have asked the question in a different way. I'll post another question.